# How to perform re substitutions on <p> tags within a specific class?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I have an html file that has instances of:

```
<p>[CR][LF]
Here is the text etc
```

and:

```
...here is the last part of the text.[CR][LF]
</p>
```

where `[CR]` and `[LF]` represent carriage returns and new lines resp.

These paragraphs are within divs with a specific class eg `my_class`.

I want to target the paragraph tags within this specific div class and perform the following substitution:

```
# remove new line after opening <p> tag
re.sub("<p>\n+", "<p>", div)
# remove new line before closing </p> tag
re.sub("<p>\n+", "<p>", div)
```

My approach is therefore to:

- Open the html file
- Isolate the specific divs
- Isolate the `<p>` tags within these divs
- Perform substitutions only on these `<p>` tags
- Write the amended contents back to the original html file

This is what I have so far but the logic fails when it gets to the substitutions and writing back to the file:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
# open the html file in read mode
html_file = open('file.html', 'r')
# convert to string
html_file_as_string = html_file.read()
# close the html file
html_file.close()
# create a beautiful soup object 
bs_html_file_as_string = BeautifulSoup(html_file_as_string, "lxml")
# isolate divs with specific class
for div in bs_html_file_as_string.find_all('div', {'class': 'my_class'}):
    # perform the substitutions
    re.sub("<p>\n+", "<p>", div)
    re.sub("\n+</p>", "</p>", div)
# open original file in write mode
html_file = open('file', 'w')
# write bs_html_file_as_string (with substitutions made) to file
html_file.write(bs_html_file_as_string)
# close the html file
html_file.close()
```

I have also been looking at beautiful soup's [replace_with](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#replace-with) but am not sure if it is relevant here.

**Edit:**

The solution below showed me an alternative way to complete the task without using re.sub.

However, I need to perform another substitution and still do not know if it is possible to do a re.sub `within a specific class`, `within a paragraph`.  Specifically, in the following example, I want to replace all the `[CR][LF]`'s with `</p>\n<p>`.  I had envisaged this would happen with the sub:

```
re.sub('\n+', r'</p>\n<p>', str)
```

**Screenshot from SciTE editor showing carriage returns and new lines:**

[image]

**Demo HTML (demo_html.html):**

```
<html>
<body>
<p>lalalalalalalala</p>
<p>lalalalalalalala</p>
<div class="my_class">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
Lorem ipsum..consectetur adipiscing elit.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit."Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet", consectetur adipisc'ing elit.Lorem ipsum dolor...sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit..
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit..
.....Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
</div>
<p>lalalalalalalala</p>
<p>lalalalalalalala</p>
</body>
</html>
```

**Demo Python (demo_python.py):**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

with open('demo_html.html', 'r') as html_file:
    html_file_as_string = html_file.read()
bs_html_file_as_string = BeautifulSoup(html_file_as_string, "lxml")
for div in bs_html_file_as_string.find_all('div', {'class': 'my_class'}):
    for p in div.find('p'):
    p.string.replace('\n','</p>\n<p>')
with open('demo_html.html', 'w') as html_file:
    html_file.write(bs_html_file_as_string.renderContents())

print 'finished'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`p.string.strip()` will remove leading, trailing spaces.

`p.string.replaceWith(NEW_STRING)` will replace the text of p tag to NEW_STRING.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open('file.html', 'r') as f:
    html_file_as_string = f.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_file_as_string, "lxml")
for div in soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'my_class'}):
    for p in div.find('p'):
        p.string.replace_with(p.string.strip())
with open('file', 'w') as f:
    f.write(soup.renderContents())
```

BTW, `re.sub(..)` return substituted string. It does not replace substitute original string.

```
>>> import re
>>> text = '   hello'
>>> re.sub('\s+', '', text)
'hello'
>>> text
'   hello'
```

**EDIT**

Code edited to match edited question:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open('file.html', 'r') as f:
    html_file_as_string = f.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_file_as_string, "lxml")
for div in soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'my_class'}):
    for p in div.findAll('p'):
        new = BeautifulSoup(u'\n'.join(u'<p>{}</p>'.format(line.strip()) for line in p.text.splitlines() if line), 'html.parser')
        p.replace_with(new)
with open('file', 'w') as f:
    f.write(soup.renderContents())
```

Comment: this won't work if the `p` tag has subtags or is empty [simple testcase](http://pastebin.com/ZgdxY8dg)

Comment: This solution is working and showed me how to use `p.string.strip()`, however I have updated the original post with further details requiring another `re.sub`-like modification and I cannot figure out how to apply similar logic to the `p.string.strip()` solution to this.   So I don't know if I should be continuing to seek to know how to apply the `re.sub` solution or an alternative similar to `p.string.strip()`.

Comment: @user1063287, Can you show your file.html by uploading file somewhere?

Comment: Traceback:  ... `new = BeautifulSoup('\n'.join('<p>{}</p>'.format(line.strip()) for line in p.text.splitlines() if line), 'lxml')
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u201c' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)`.  I am guessing this is referring to `"` in the paragraphs.

Comment: Opening and closing `<html>` and `<body>` tags are being added at the beginning and end of the div eg `<div><html><body><p>stuff 1</p><p>stuff 2</p><p>stuff 3</p></html></body></div>`.  Possibly from using 'lxml' as parser on the `new` Beautiful Soup variable.

Comment: Trying with `html.parser` now.

Comment: @user1063287, Sorry, I didn't notice that.  I updated the code  to use `html.parser`.

Comment: For others reference:  

1.  beautiful soup:  create beautiful soup object for each line
2.  .format():  get data from the following list comprehension and insert in between paragraph tags
3.  list comprehension:  strip each line of text within p (where lines are created with .splitlines method), if there is a line
4.  .join():  use a new line as separator between each set of paragraph tags
5.  .replace_with():  replace each instance of p with newly formatted content

And the freaky thing is - it works.  How do I learn the skills you have?  Book/course recommendations welcomed.  Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check if the first and last content element of your `p` is a text node (an instance of `bs4.NavigableString`, which is a subclass of `str`). This should work:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, NavigableString
import re

html_file_as_string = """
<p>test1</p>

<p>
test2</p>
<p>test3
</p>

<p></p>

<p>
test4
<b>...</b>
test5
</p>

<p><b>..</b>
</p>

<p>
<br></p>

"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_file_as_string, "lxml")
for p in soup.find_all('p'):
    if p.contents:
        if isinstance(p.contents[0], NavigableString):
            p.contents[0].replace_with(p.contents[0].lstrip())
        if isinstance(p.contents[-1], NavigableString):
            p.contents[-1].replace_with(p.contents[-1].rstrip())

print(soup)
```

output:

```
<html><body><p>test1</p>
<p>test2</p>
<p>test3</p>
<p></p>
<p>test4
<b>...</b>
test5</p>
<p><b>..</b></p>
<p><br/></p>
</body></html>
```

Using regular expressions to parse/process html is almost always a bad idea.

Answer (score -1):

results from the substitution in the for loop are not stored; you could try something like:

```
import re

strings = ['foo', 'bar', 'qux']

for k, s in enumerate(strings):
    strings[k] = re.sub('foo', 'cheese', s)
```